# Style divs /w same class based on parent-child relation (bootstrap classes)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, umbraco

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
    <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
</div>
```

Desired effect:

```css
.row {
    ~div:nth-child(1) /*also tried*/ ~div:first-child /*also tried*/ ~div:first-of-type {
        position:relative;
        left:5vw;
    }

    ~div:nth-child(2) /*also tried*/ ~div:last-child /*also tried*/ ~div:last-of-type {
        position:relative;
        right:5vw;
    }
}
```

**Consequence:**

I am able to select the children of .row
testing with color:red; I style the contents of .col-md-6 (they are set to inherit color)
testing with background-color:red; I style the .row
and the positioning again style the grandchildren of the .row

**Notice:**

The class .col-md-6 in umbraco back-end cannot change, as these are in use other places in the web app. I am not looking to add classes manually in the back end nor add classes with JS based on position

How can I get
    `:nth-child(1)` / `:first-child` / `:first-of-type`
to target the correct div, and only the div itself, for positioning?

Comment: maybe try `div:nth-of-type(1)`

Comment: I changed to position:page; and it worked
The selector, for some styling, selected multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for positioning

```
position:page;
```

Will work for the positioning inside of the .row

Answer (score 0):

```css
div { width: 100% }

.row div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
.row div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
  <div class="col-md-6">...</div>  
</div>
```